# How to convert code page ascii to code page 1255

Tags: c#

I have this line serialPort.Encoding = Encoding.ASCII;

I need the code page 1255

How I can convert it ?

thank's in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
serialPort.Encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(1255);
```

Comment: Or rather GetEncoding(1255) if the OP *really* wants 1255 instead of 1252 :)

Comment: Then how about marking this answer as the accepted answer? And do not forget to do the same in all your other questions. Thank you.